# What are the different endings for the game UnEpic?

Tags: unepic

I heard that UnEpic has multiple endings. I am curious about how the story ends. Could someone please outline whatever ending story you have seen so far?

I have put in a lot of hours but cannot continue playing anymore for the reasons outlined [here](http://videogamegeek.com/thread/906827/unepic-it-will-annoy-you-unepic-review).

Comment: If the question is asking specifically for ending details, it's self evident that there will be spoilers.  There is no need to indicate such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From multiple sites I have found the following:

From Steam chat room, and [Video Game Geek site](http://videogamegeek.com/thread/906827/unepic-it-will-annoy-you-unepic-review):

> There are 3 chests in the last area of which you can only open one. Depending on what chest you chose the ending will differ.

This means that there are a possible 3 endings. According to VideoGeek it seems that all 3 endings a poorly constructed and your character dies 100% of the time.

There are three final bosses. Each boss correlates to a certain chest. Each on represents the "demon in the player" and you will die. Then the game resets. There is no way to beat UnEpic. Only a way to finish it.

The third ending which you can't find can be found in this video:[UnEpic ending 3.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqvVkmG1EYU)

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting together this info. However, I was expecting a more detailed response. What is the story exactly for each of the 3 endings?

Comment: After much searching I've finally found 2 of the endings. So I'm updating the question with this info. I just need the 3rd ending now.

Comment: @Mugen which 2 did you find?

Comment: I found 2 youtube videos. One was for some death scene in which the main character gets a forecast of death but then that blue angel tells him that it's not him who will die but someone he likes. So next scene shows him 2 years later living aloof and watching game of thrones when a character dies. The 2nd video was the one where the angel tells him he's got a few years of freedom and then will be working as a slave. So he tries to "live life to the fullest" and gets a gf. Ends up working as a slave for her.

Comment: @Mugen The third one is the one I mentioned in the answer. You have to fight with your "personal demon".

Comment: Oh Where is it? I don't see any text or link to it. Also, I tried googling it but still didn't find it. I feel kinda tired of googling for this game's endings. Don't know why they are so tough to find.

Comment: @Mugen I'll get the full list tonight

Answer (score 13):

There are three youtube videos with the three different endings:

[Eternal slavery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMrMKwYOuO4) (chest on the right):

[Horrible Death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqvVkmG1EYU) (chest on the left):

[Eternal agony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snALPTK2-Ak) (chest in the middle):